# Не работает ::first-line на мобильном телефоне как исправить?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Мне нужно сделать чтобы 2 слова начинались с большой буквы (первая буква в 2 словах с большой буквы). На desctop нормально все работает, на телефоне почему-то все с маленькой. Как решить проблему ?

```css
.search-number__tcountry {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 17px;
  letter-spacing: 0.008em;
  color: #A0A0A0;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

.search-number__tcountry::first-line{
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<span class="search-number__tcountry">UNITED STATES</span>
```

Comment: Приложите и ваш HTML пожалуйста

Comment: <span class="search-number__tcountry">UNITED STATES</span>

Comment: Приложить - значит вставить в сам вопрос. В вашем случае прямо в Фрагмент кода

Comment: Добавил. Не так понял.

Comment: У вас работает как надо, когда вы нажимаете на "Выполнить код"? Просто у меня буквы остались в нижнем регистре

Comment: На стэке почему то показывает в нижним регистре, на сайте все ок. На телефоне все с маленькой.

Comment: А, чёрт) У вас же `span`, а надо блочный элемент https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line

Answer (score 0):

[В доках](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line) написано что нужен именно блочный элемент, например `p` или `div`:

```css
.search-number__tcountry {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 17px;
  letter-spacing: 0.008em;
  color: #A0A0A0;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

.search-number__tcountry::first-line{
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<p class="search-number__tcountry">UNITED STATES</p>
<span class="search-number__tcountry">UNITED STATES</span>
<div class="search-number__tcountry">UNITED STATES</div>
<div>
  <span class="search-number__tcountry">UNITED STATES</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я просто не добавил у меня span в div с flexbox. Я чего туплю)))

Comment: Но на мобильном телефоне не работает ::first-line

Comment: @Алексей Я добавил ещё пример с `div`-ом. Дело не в том находится ли текст в каком-то блочном элементе. Текст должен находится непосредственно в блочном элементе

Comment: я понял логику. Поменял span на div вначале на desctop все ок, на телефоне не работает, потом поменял на p тоже самое. Почему не работает не пойму.

Comment: Попробуйте в приватной вкладке телефона. Может старый код, сохранился. А ещё откройте этот вопрос с телефона и запустите мой код и посмотрите на результат выполнения. У меня сработало и на телефоне

Comment: Наверно из-за display: flex где, что-то перебивает

Comment: Кстати, да он сбивает эти стили. Не скажу пока что почему, но догадка верная

Comment: @Алексей этот момент даже в доках указан https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers

Comment: Я значит убрал display: flex  с блока div где внутри <p class="search-number__tcountry">UNITED STATES</p> на desctop все норм на телефоне не работает

Comment: Тут уже не подскажу, так) Приложите минимальный воспроизводимый пример. НО убедитесь, что когда вы открываете этот вопрос в телефоне и нажимаете на "Выполнить код", то у вас воспроизводится ошибка

Comment: Я зашел через телефон посмотреть ваш пример, у меня все маленькие. IOS через google chrome. А через, что вы смотрели ?

Comment: @Алексей Я смотрел через Android  Firefox